# Is it possible to mix a luminescent drink?

Tags: visible-light, physical-chemistry, home-experiment, chemical-compounds, fluorescence

Is it possible to create a drink that glows? In other words, is it possible to create a non-poisonous drink that fluoresces? Are there known compounds suitable for that? If not, then what about a milder condition: UV-induced luminescence?

DISCLAIMER: I am neither going to drink this by myself nor do any experiments, this is just curiosity. I may only use such substances if they are available from legal producers and are approved by the FDA or whatever.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a chemistry question.

Answer (score 5):

[Tonic water fluoresces](http://www.scientificamerican.com/article/shining-science-explore-glow-in-the-dark-water/) - if you shine UV (black light) on it, it will glow.

From the above link:

[image]

As a follow-up I did the experiment in my own kitchen - with sparkling water and tonic in two glasses side by side.

[image]

The same glasses under UV light:
[image]

To remove any doubt - the glass on the right had the tonic water. I removed the white paper background in the UV picture as the paper itself showed some effect of the whitener added...

Comment: I didn't know that before. Go science!

Comment: Hmmm ... the tonic waters I've tried glow much whiter than that. The color in the image is what I see when I use OxiClean (also mentioned in the article, thought they have discontinued their glowiest product).

Comment: @dmckee - I agree it looks rather blue; but remember that the human eye is really terrific at auto white balance adjustment: we don't really notice how yellow tungsten light is. This _may_ be the "real" color; or it may be a question of white balance adjustment. Or they used a stock photo in the article. The bubbles look suspiciously large, too.

Comment: Assuming I can find my UV LEDs, I'll take a picture of some glowing tonic water when I'm home and post it in chat later. I already have a picture of some glowing OxiClear to post for comparison.

Comment: I have the LEDs. Bring the tonic. I have some gin - we can see if it still glows...

Comment: That is an artist's illustration.

Mt. Dew fluoresces rather dramatically.

Answer (score 3):

Try fluorescent dye (non-toxic, please!). [Highlighter ink](http://chemistry.about.com/od/glowinthedarkprojects/a/glowingbubbles.htm) can work for ordinary tap water (more detail [here](http://www.wikihow.com/Make-Water-Glow)). Fluorescent paints and glowsticks can also produce decent amounts of light; **however, all three of the above methods do not produce substances that are safe to drink**. Always be careful when using dyes and other chemicals in beverages.

[Putting rum on the surface and igniting it](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qntlN_km34w) also seems to work; this, too, is dangerous, even if you don't drink the resulting mixture!

For anyone who's curious, this is what the flaming rum looks like (probably not what you were going for, admittedly):

[image]

A picture of the water glowing from highlighter ink (mage used under Fair Use):

[image]

Comment: Thanks for adding the "unsafe to drink" bit. I was about to comment on that...

Comment: @Floris Yep. I'd rather not kill the person asking the question!

Comment: Ok - with the burning rum I just had to upvote. I don't think it was the point of the question though. But it's a bright idea. Hehe.